# After Java Files.write(), the last access time is modified to a few milliseconds later?

Tags: java, windows, filesystems, nio

Here's the basic setup, writing to a text file.

Java 11.0.13 Corretto, Windows 10.

```
Files.write(path, stuff);

System.out.println(((FileTime) Files.getAttribute(p, "lastAccessTime")).toMillis());
System.out.println(((FileTime) Files.getAttribute(p, "lastModifiedTime")).toMillis());

Thread.sleep(100);

System.out.println(((FileTime) Files.getAttribute(p, "lastAccessTime")).toMillis());
System.out.println(((FileTime) Files.getAttribute(p, "lastModifiedTime")).toMillis());
```

I'd expect all 4 times to be the same. But what actually happens is something like this:

```
1642405963200
1642405963200

1642405963207
1642405963200
```

For some reason, the last access time is updated to a few milliseconds later (7 in this particular run).

What's the reason for this behavior?

EDIT: Further testing shows this only occurred to to the usage of the iterable parameter of the `write` method.

The following results in the strange behavior shown above.

```
Files.write(path, Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
```

Either of the following does not, and last access time is consistent as expected.

```
Files.write(p, "1\n2\n3\n".getBytes());
Files.writeString(p, "1\n2\n3\n");
```

`

Answer (score 0):

If other threads read it in same time, you will get a new accessTime